# Deleting a file from a folder gets stuck

Tags: windows, windows-10, download, recycle-bin

I'm trying to delete a `.zip` file from my Downloads folder, but when I click on it to delete it I get this message:

[image]

And nothing happens. I let it sit for an hour and nothing is going on.

Comment: try deleting it from the command line. does the file name have funny characters, or is it quite long?

Comment: Tried Shift-Delete?

Comment: Looks like shift+delete also gets clogged

Comment: perhaps its time for a disk check. you may have a problem with the indexes or storage location of the tile.

Comment: Is it safe to say that waiting for it to finish is not the solution here? Or could I try hitting delete and leaving my computer on overnight?

Comment: You might try renaming the file then deleting it. Maybe there's an invalid character in there.

Comment: Happen to me today that Antivirus was accesing (and maybe uploading) files before release them and let me delete them. I disabled active protection for 5 min and worked flawlessly. Note: I was deleting bunch of files and folders. Doing the same with little amount elements didn't failed.

Answer (score 1):

Just needed a regular reboot. I hadn't shutdown my laptop in a while and there were pending Windows updates too. This did the job.

Answer (score 0):

It could be locked by some process, e.g. antivirus scanning.

1. Try a true reboot (not hybrid shutdown) by entering

> shutdown -s -t 0

or to force restart,

> shutdown -r -t 0

Then try to delete it again.

2. If that doesn't work, use a tool to check if the file is locked such as [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/download.htm).
3. Or try Mawarebytes [FileASSASSIN](https://www.malwarebytes.com/fileassassin/) .

Comment: That command doesn't restart the computer. It just shuts it down. Big difference for people who might use remote desktop. `shutdown -r -t 0` restarts it.